# Stripe update payment on subscription to make it use the default on the customer

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

So we have some Stripe customers with subscriptions that are setup with payment methods and they work just fine.

The issue is, when the subscription were setup, They were explicitly given the payment method id, instead of letting it default to the one on the customer ( dun... dun.. the same payment method. ).

So what this means is, if a customer updates their payment method, we have to explicitly update each subscription to use it, since the subscription has its own payment method ( the old default ).

The question is, without rebuilding the subscription, how do we tell the subscription to forget about the payment method it has, and start using the default source on the Customer?

The docs on the Subscription talk here about setting the default value, but not how do you clear it?
[image: stripe sub documentation]

I attempted to null it out by running this node.js snippet:

```
    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.update(
        subscriptionId,
        {
            default_payment_method: undefined
        }
    );
```

and it succeeded, but did nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to send an empty string to clear the value of `default_payment_method`:

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.update(
        subscriptionId,
        {
            default_payment_method: "",
        }
    );
```

Then, if `default_source` isn't set on the subscription, the customer's  `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` or `default_source` will be used.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out on Monday.